# eval_metric_ops display under family on tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml-engine

With scalar summaries in tensorflow 1.3 I can now define a 'family' that will help to group the relevant metrics under the same tensorboard tab. For example if I have two summary scalars defined below:

```
precision = precision(labels, predictions)
recall = recall(labels, predictions)
```

I can then display these under a single tab in tensorboard by performing the following:

```
tf.summary.scalar('precision', precision, family = 'precision/recall')
tf.summary.scalar('recall', recall, family = 'precision/recall')
```

I want to repeat this behavior using eval_metric_ops for evaluation summaries, but I can't manage to find any way to do this.  For example, I would want one tab that had tf.metrics.precision and tf.metrics.recall under the same scalars tab.  Is there any way to control the tab name used for eval_metric_ops?

I am running this within an ML Engine Experiment function, so a general solution that can be passed to the tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a custom estimator, you can use slash-separated prefixes to metric keys to control what family they appear under in Tensorboard.

Specifically, if you emit a metric with the key `my_family/accuracy`, as in the following:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:

    accuracy = ...
    loss = ...

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
        loss=loss,
        eval_metric_ops={'my_family/accuracy': tf.metrics.mean(accuracy)},
    )

  else:
    ...
```

the `accuracy` metric will appear as part of the `my_family` family in tensorboard.

Answer (score 1):

With a canned estimator I don't think there is any way to control the family of the built in metrics. But you could add a hook that adds additional metrics as a `eval_hook` argument to `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` using a [`tf.train.SummarySaverHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SummarySaverHook) and you will be able control the family of these newly defined hooks.

With a custom estimator you'll do the same except you'll add the hook to them to `evaluation_hooks` in your returned `EstimatorSpec` so you can specify metric families as normal.

Comment: I am using a custom estimator, however while I know how to define families as normal for tf.summary.scalar, I'm not sure how to define metric families for any tf.metrics? There are metrics_collections and weight_collections but I haven't had any luck getting this to actually group them together in tabs on tensorboard.

Comment: My understanding is that eval_metric_ops is a dict of metric results keyed by the name. For the metrics themselves there is no "family" and I don't see any way to specify a family for any metric. Could you clarify how to specify metric families?

Comment: You're right, It turns out theirs no way to control the family of the built in hooks either, so you'll have to follow the same approach that you would use for a canned estimator (updated the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will try to implement your suggestion.  One alternative that I explored was to just output scalar's during Modes.EVAL, but they are not displaying and it's unclear why. I asked this in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889273/ml-engine-experiment-eval-tf-summary-scalar-not-displaying-in-tensorboard