# ML Engine Experiment eval tf.summary.scalar not displaying in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to output some summary scalars in an ML engine experiment at both train and eval time.  `tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)` is correctly outputting the summary scalars for both training and evaluation on the same plot in tensorboard. However, I am also trying to output other metrics at both train and eval time and they are only outputting at train time.  The code immediately follows `tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)` but does not appear to work.  For example, the code as follows is only outputting for TRAIN, but not EVAL. The only difference is that these are using custom accuracy functions, but they are working for TRAIN

```
if mode in (Modes.TRAIN, Modes.EVAL):
    loss = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, outputs, weights)
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

    sequence_accuracy = sequence_accuracy(targets, predictions,weights)
    tf.summary.scalar('sequence_accuracy', sequence_accuracy)
```

Does it make any sense why loss would plot in tensorboard for both TRAIN & EVAL, while sequence_accuracy would only plot for TRAIN?

Could this behavior somehow be related to the warning I received "Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `summary` node in the graph is just a node. It still needs to be evaluated (outputting a protobuf string), and that string still needs to be written to a file. It's not evaluated in training mode because it's not upstream of the `train_op` in your graph, and even if it were evaluated, it wouldn't be written to a file unless you specified a [`tf.train.SummarySaverHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SummarySaverHook) as one of you `training_chief_hooks` in your `EstimatorSpec`. Because the `Estimator` class doesn't assume you want any extra evaluation during training, normally evaluation is only done during the EVAL phase, and you just increase `min_eval_frequency` or `checkpoint_frequency` to get more evaluation datapoints.

If you *really really* want to log a summary during training here's how you'd do it:

```
def model_fn(mode, features, labels, params):
  ...
  if mode == Modes.TRAIN:
    # loss is already written out during training, don't duplicate the summary op
    loss = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, outputs, weights)
    sequence_accuracy = sequence_accuracy(targets, predictions,weights)
    seq_sum_op = tf.summary.scalar('sequence_accuracy', sequence_accuracy)
    with tf.control_depencencies([seq_sum_op]):
       train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      loss=loss,
      mode=mode,
      train_op=train_op,
      training_chief_hooks=[tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
          save_steps=100,
          output_dir='./summaries',
          summary_op=seq_sum_op
      )]
    )
```

But it's better to just increase your eval frequency and make an `eval_metric_ops` for accuracy with `tf.metrics.streaming_accuracy`

Comment: I'm a little confused because you say "it's not evaluated in training mode" however the issue that I am facing is that it is outputting for training and it is not outputting for eval mode -- was this a typo or am I already observing unexpected behavior by seeing training metrics being displayed in tensorboard?

Comment: Separately, the reason that I want to do this outside of eval_metric_ops is that I want to have a single plot that shows accuracy during training time and accuracy during evaluation time as another gauge for potential overfitting or some sign that the predictions being generated were materially different. For example, if I am training an RNN with feed_previous=False and evaluating with feed_previous=True I want to get a sense of how the accuracy is during training with feed_previous=False and compare to eval with feed_previous=True.

Comment: I'm a little confused, Estimator already overlays training and eval statistics.

Comment: I think that I realized where I was going wrong/confusing myself. I was trying to use TF 1.3's new "family" argument to group tensorboard plots together.  This functionality did not exist with eval_metric_ops so then they would generate their own plots that weren't underneath 'family'. Further, during Modes.EVAL I would try to write tf.summary.scalar's with the family functionality but those would never display because they were being written as separate event files and tensorboard would only use the "latest" which was the eval_metric_ops event file

Comment: So, it looks like the takeaway here is that I really just can't use TF 1.3's family functionality yet if I want to also have the eval metrics display on the same graph and I should just pass all EVAL metrics through eval_metric_ops

Comment: Having said that, I'm not convinced by your suggestion that you must add a SummarySaverHook during training. In the Custom Estimator census sample, if I generate probabilities and predicted_indices during Modes.TRAIN and add another scalar after ['loss'](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/customestimator/trainer/model.py#L197) such as `sequence_accuracy = sequence_accuracy(targets, predictions,weights)
     tf.summary.scalar('sequence_accuracy', sequence_accuracy)` then I do get the sequence_accuracy plotted in my tensorboard?

Comment: You;ll need the hook, because those ops don't actually write out summaries. All they do is convert the Tensor object to a string Tensor with the serialize proto representation of the summary. You need the hook to write out those string Tensors to files.

Comment: acknowledged. How come the summaries in Modes.TRAIN are currently displaying in tensorboard currently without the hook? As I understand your explanation, this would seem impossible?

Comment: Only loss is. Basically loss is automatically written out as a summary during both training and eval, because it's a required return value for EstimatorSpec in both of those modes, and doesn't require any extra processing. So it's baked into Estimator.